# Automatically move data labels outside of pie chart in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a pie chart in Excel, my data labels are overlaid directly over each slice in the pie - but I want my labels outside the area of the pie (but within the general chart area).

I can drag them individually, but I remember that older versions (2003?) had the labels like how I want them, but 2013 doesn't.

Is there a GUI function or button for this, or a VBA feature?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue (I think). I have basically used

> position = xlLabelPositionBestFit

However, other positions are available. Right click the xlLabelPositionBestFit in your VBA window and list properties/methods to see the choices.

```
Sub ResetLabels()

 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart XX").Activate
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
 Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit
 Selection.AutoText = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be required VBA code and play with data labels properties such as;
`ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).DataLabel.Left = 50
ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).DataLabel.Top = 200`